# How to call a function present parallel to calling function in React context API

Tags: javascript, reactjs, jsx

I have a function `update()` in `WebContextProvider`, from which I want to call another function `updateAgain()` which is also present in `WebContextProvider`. Below is the code for reference.

```
import React, { createContext, Component } from 'react';

export const WebContext = createContext();

class WebContextProvider extends Component {
    state = {
        someState: 1,
    };

    render() {
        return (
            <WebContext.Provider
                value={{
                    data: ...this.state,
                    update: () => {
                       //call updateAgain() from here
                    },
                    updateAgain:() => {
                       //call this from update()
                    }
               }}
            >
                {this.props.children}
            </WebContext.Provider>
        );
    }
}

export default WebContextProvider;
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can declare the functions above the class declaration and provide them inside the value of the context provider, or if you need access to the state you'll have to define them inside your class and send references to the methods.

External functions example:

```
import React, { createContext, Component } from 'react';

export const WebContext = createContext();

const update = () => { /* Do something, you can call here updateAgain() */ };

const updateAgain = () => { /* Do something else */ };

export default class WebContextProvider extends Component {
    state = {
        someState: 1,
    };

    render() {
        return (
            <WebContext.Provider
                value={{
                    data: ...this.state,
                    update,
                    updateAgain
                }}>
                {this.props.children}
            </WebContext.Provider>
        );
    }
}
```

Example with class methods, when you need to use `state`:

```
import React, { createContext, Component } from 'react';

export const WebContext = createContext();

export default class WebContextProvider extends Component {
    state = {
        someState: 1,
    };

    render() {
        return (
            <WebContext.Provider
                value={{
                    data: ...this.state,
                    update: this.update,
                    updateAgain: this.updateAgain
                }}>
                {this.props.children}
            </WebContext.Provider>
        );
    }

    update = () => { /* Do something, you can call here this.updateAgain() or use this.state */ }

    updateAgain = () => { /* Do something else, you can use this.state here */ }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use `this.propertyName` to refer to any property on the object instance provided that you use a regular `function` instead of an arrow function.

```js
const ctxObject = {
  first: () => {
   console.log("first");
  },
  second: function() {
    console.log("second");
    this.first();
  }
}

ctxObject.second();
```